# How to schedule an RDS snapshot and restore in the same script

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-rds, aws-glue

so I'm scheduling an AWS python job (through AWS Glue Python shell) that is supposed to clone a MySQL RDS database (best way to take a snapshot and restore?) and perform sql queries on the database. I have the boto3 library on the Python Shell and an SQL Python Library I loaded. I have this code currently

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('rds')
# Create a snapshot of the database
snapshot_response = client.create_db_snapshot(
    DBSnapshotIdentifier='snapshot-identifier',
    DBInstanceIdentifier='instance-db',
)

# Restore db from snapshot
restore_response = client.restore_db_instance_from_db_snapshot(
    DBInstanceIdentifier = 'restored-db',
    DBSnapshotIdentifier = 'snapshot-identifier',
)

# Code that will perform sql queries on the restored-db database.
```

However, the `client.restore_db_instance_from_db_snapshot` fails because it says the snapshot is being created. So I understand that this means these calls are asynchronous. But I am not sure how to get this snapshot restore to work (either by making them synchronous - not a good idea?) or by some other way. Thanks for the help in advance :).

Comment: The calls are not asynchronous in the sense that you are implying. They are actually synchronous, which is what you want. Not sure why you think making them synchronous would be a bad idea. The problem you are seeing is because the `create_db_snapshot` simply triggers the creation of a snapshot and then returns, it doesn't wait for AWS to complete the creation of the snapshot. For obvious reasons, as creating a snapshot on a really large database can take hours. If you explicitly want to want for the snapshot before continuing with your program, you have to explicitly call the `waiter`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a **waiter**:

```py
waiter = client.get_waiter('db_cluster_snapshot_available')
```

> Polls `RDS.Client.describe_db_cluster_snapshots()` every 30 seconds until a successful state is reached. An error is returned after 60 failed checks.

See: [class RDS.Waiter.DBClusterSnapshotAvailable](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/rds.html#RDS.Waiter.DBClusterSnapshotAvailable)